# How to start Docker if address is already in use?

Tags: docker

How can I start docker on Ubuntu 20.04, if it complains that address is already in use? I tried

```
docker-compose up -d
Starting relaatiotietokannat_db_1 ... 
Starting relaatiotietokannat_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for relaatiotietokannat_db_1  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint relaatiotietokannat_db_1 (02444b3d0c2841a4fe702cf2705fbd5a869e44e7f258ecfbcea764ead989fcb4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint relaatiotietokannat_db_1 (02444b3d0c2841a4fe702cf2705fbd5a869e44e7f258ecfbcea764ead989fcb4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that port `3306` is already used by another process. You have to either stop that process and release the port or tell `docker` to use another port. You may find out which process is currently using port `3306` by executing `netstat -lntep |grep 3306`